# Buiding docker containers for golang applications without calling go build

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I'm building my first Dockerfile for a go application and I don't understand while `go build` or `go install` are considered a necessary part of the docker container.

I know this can be avoided using muilt-stage but I don't know why it was ever put in the container image in the first place.

What I would expect:

- I have a go application 'go-awesome'
- I can build it locally from cmd/go-awesome

My Dockerfile contains not much more than

> COPY go-awesome .
>
> CMD ["go-awesome"]

What is the downside of this configuration?  What do I gain by instead doing

> COPY . .
>
> RUN go get ./...
>
> RUN go install ./..

Links to posts showing building go applications as part of the Dockerfile

https://www.callicoder.com/docker-golang-image-container-example/

https://blog.codeship.com/building-minimal-docker-containers-for-go-applications/

https://www.cloudreach.com/blog/containerize-this-golang-dockerfiles/

https://medium.com/travis-on-docker/how-to-dockerize-your-go-golang-app-542af15c27a2

Comment: I would definitely agree with you, i.e. following "way 2" in your last link. Building inside the container seems ridiculous and is probably a holdover from people who came to Go after getting used to something like Node or Ruby in containers.

Comment: how is this different than someone building a node project locally and then only copying/running it the dockerfile?

Comment: It doesn't seem any different from copying a node project, which is why it baffles me that every blog post I've seen on "dockerize a go container" seems to consider this the default behavior.  Certainly a go application can run standalone.

Comment: You never want to deploy a binary that isn't built in a clean, reproducible environment. If you build the binary in a docker container (I suggest the multistage build in one container then transfer to a smaller deployment container) you get that for free.

Comment: A node project is much more sensitive to its operating environment varying from its "npm install" environment; plus, since a node app requires node installed in order to run, the benefit of building outside the container is minimal. With Go, there is no reason for the operating environment to have Go installed at all, and it is not particularly sensitive to differences between build vs operating environment.

Comment: @JimB  "You never want to deploy a binary that isn't built in a clean, reproducible environment."  If I stick the code on github and put the binary in my container - what's the downside?  OK, a fellow dev would need to reproduce my environment, but that seems so natural anyway. If I have someone else's container with someone else's go environment and sources, it would still be painful to try to develop and build inside that container.  I'd much rather clone the source locally and start from there.

Comment: @Adrian  I'm an old C++ programmer so perhaps that's why building inside a container seems grotesque to me.  "Here's a container, hope you have 30 minutes and a few hundred MBs to spare"

Comment: I definitely agree. Building in a container seems inherently wrong to me, unless that container exists for building (e.g. a build agent running in a container, that's producing an artifact to be deployed in a different container dedicated to operating the app).

Comment: @kSet: If I'm deploying a binary to a production system, I don't want it built on another developer's personal machine, where there's no verification of the toolchain, dependencies, or source files. Granted the go toolchain is much simpler than most, so there's less room for failure, but why leave room for errors when you can easily have a reproducible build? It's not like this is a new concept; OS distributions have built their binaries with verified sources in clean (chroot, jails, containers, etc) environments forever.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you can compile your application locally and simply copy the executable into a suitable docker image.

However, there are benefits to compiling the application inside the docker build, particularly for larger projects with multiple collaborators. Specifically the following reasons come to mind:

- There are no local dependencies (aside from docker) required to build the application source. Someone wouldn't even need to have go installed. This is especially valuable for projects in which multiple languages are in use. Consider someone who might want to edit an HTML template inside of a go project and see what that looked like in the container runtime..
- The build environment (version of go, dependency managment, file paths...) is constant. Any external dependencies can be safely managed and maintained via the Dockerfile.

Comment: That's a useful point - anyone can shell into the container and make updates freely.  It still seems like a rare use case - why poke around inside a container when github exists?   Perhaps docker superusers find it more intuitive.

Comment: For polyglot applications with non-full-stack developers, I can see some potential (albeit minor) advantages. The second point seems moot if you have a CI build server doing your builds.

Comment: @Adrian  
Moot for a production / release deployment perhaps.  
But it's certainly beneficial to the development process. I don't want to waste time debating with my colleagues and collaborators if something is wrong with the code, or if it is just an issue with some obscure difference in build environment.

Comment: @kSet  
To your point: I maintain many applications for which the Dockerfile simply copies the compiled executable into a scratch image. It's simple and works quite well. We have other tooling that orchestrates _how_ we build those executables, which is why it works well across many systems/applications. But I have several others applications with more complicated dependencies (mainly CGo build environments) for which things like a multi-stage build are immensely useful.

Comment: It mostly just makes it simpler for other people to build your docker image. Especially if you're trying to create a tiny image.  For the case of compiling a go executible that you can just drop into a scratch image, you need to apply several additional arguments to the build command. You could write this up in a README (not everyone will see it), provide a script that does it (not everyone will use it), or you can just bake it into the docker build itself...

Comment: "some obscure difference in build environment" - how often do you have this impacting Go projects? I ran into some minor issues over the course of the move to go modules but other than that, Go apps seem to "just work" in my experience. Of course, I'm not doing much cgo stuff, which I'm sure makes a big difference in that regard.

Comment: Agreed - for the most part Go's dependencies just work. But there are definitely some headaches with legacy vendor folders, and git repositories that decide to change their name... But you're right - aside from switching dependency management tools, most of the issues I've had have been specific to external dependencies on c libraries.